# Using Travis for CI of Chef cookbook with E2 instance just hangs on Waiting for SSH service after creating instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, travis-ci, test-kitchen

Fixed a problem like this a while ago but somehow stumbled into again - messing with my head.

Using just a simple wrapper-cookbook for Sudo to demonstrate Travis CI job using EC2 for instance provisioning, configuration, and testing.

While both the default Rake (vagrant based test) and the ci version run successfully from a local machine - during a Travis run it will provision the new instance and then once available wait in an endless loop...

```
Waiting for SSH service on ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22, retrying in 3 seconds
Waiting for SSH service on ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22, retrying in 3 seconds
Waiting for SSH service on ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22, retrying in 3 seconds
```

Any ideas on how to correct? It seems like Kitchen doesn't actually pick up the .pem when running on Travis. I tried this as a Jenkins job running in a private datacenter server to try and replicate the conditions on the Travis container (e.g., not a dev box) but that actually worked. So it is something about the Travis config I am missing. And setting a connection_timeout in transport doesn't seem to get recognized...

Below are relevant files:

.kitchen.ec2.yml

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: cloud
    driver_plugin: ec2
    driver_config:
      aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
      aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
      aws_ssh_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_SSH_KEY_ID'] %>
      aws_ssh_key_path: <%= ENV['AWS_SSH_KEY_PATH'] %>
      image_id: ami-6d1c2007
      require_chef_omnibus: true
      instance_type: t2.nano
      associate_public_ip: true
      block_device_mappings:
        - ebs_device_name: /dev/sda1
          ebs_volume_size: 8
          ebs_delete_on_termination: true
      tags:
        Name: ci
    transport:
      username: centos
      ssh_key: 'org_aws_ci.pem'
      connection_timeout: 10
      connection_retries: 8

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[org-sudo::default]
    attributes:
```

The before_install decompresses the travis encrypt-file of org_aws_ci.pem into the local folder - as shown above in the transport path, also where the ENV key path. The secure keys are all the necessary ENV vars.

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby
  rvm:
  - 2.2.0
  before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_844f1325c8ef_key -iv $encrypted_844f1325c8ef_iv -in org_aws_ci.pem.enc -out org_aws_ci.pem -d
  install:
  - bundle install --without vagrant
  - bundle exec berks install
  script:
  - bundle exec rake ci
  env:
    global:
    - secure: <travis encrypted key>
    - secure: <travis encrypted key>
    - secure: <travis encrypted key>
    - secure: <travis encrypted key>
```

Rakefile

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'rubocop/rake_task'
require 'foodcritic'
require 'kitchen'

namespace :style do
  desc 'Run Ruby style checks'
  RuboCop::RakeTask.new(:ruby)

  desc 'Run Chef style checks'
  FoodCritic::Rake::LintTask.new(:chef)
end

desc 'Run all style checks'
task style: %w(style:chef style:ruby)

namespace :integration do
  desc 'Run Test Kitchen with Vagrant'
  task :vagrant do
    Kitchen.logger = Kitchen.default_file_logger
    instance = Kitchen::Config.new.instances.get('default-local')
    instance.test
  end
  desc 'Run Test Kitchen in EC2'
  task :ec2 do
    Kitchen.logger = Kitchen.default_file_logger
    @loader = Kitchen::Loader::YAML.new(project_config: './.kitchen.ec2.yml')
    config = Kitchen::Config.new(loader: @loader)
    config.instances.each do |instance|
      instance.test(:always)
    end
  end
end

desc 'Run ChefSpec examples'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

desc 'Validate .travis.yml format'
task :validatetravis do
  sh 'travis lint --skip-completion-check'
end

task ci: %w(validatetravis style spec integration:ec2)
task default: %w(style spec integration:vagrant)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `.kitchen.ec2.yml`, set instead of the config key `ssh_key: 'org_aws_ci.pem'` the full file path, i.e. `ssh_key: '~/.ssh/org_aws_ci.pem'`